# image texture on UIView background. How big is too big?

Tags: ios, uiview, xamarin.ios

Do you guys think loading a 750KB png as a background everytime a UIViewController is presented is a problem?

I am noticing some small jerky movements, but nothing too bad. Interestingly enough, the device I am noticing this on, is an iPhone 4. On 3GS the movement is 100% fluid!

I am talking about the transitions (flip horizontal/cross disolve etc) that happen when a new UIViewController is presented as a modal form.

Comment: What's the view's size? (frame)

Comment: Are you running instruments while this stuttering occurs? Debugging? Try running the app by itself on both phones.

Comment: It's a full screen View. The root view of a new view controller that is presented as modal. I'm running the app directly on the phone.

Comment: Are you providing the @2x version of the image for iPhone 4?  That would explain why 3GS might be faster.

Comment: Ahh yes ofcrouse you are right. The 3GS is faster because it's not loading the 750k image

Comment: If your image does have an alpha channel or transparency, but doesn't use any transparency you can strip out the alpha channel from the image file for better performance; the OS won't have to process the alphas which are relatively costly.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say its way to big to be including in your app. You should find a repeatable section of the texture, include that, and then set the background colour to

```
[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:repeatableImage];
```

Comment: ? - 750kb doesn't sound bad. It should be cached so it's not loaded multiple times.

Comment: Thanks thats a good idea. But what if I didn't want it to be a pattern image but a full background image? We are talking about retina displays here. You need to have some detail to be visually appealing (depends on the app also) 

So what file size would you say is the max for loading as a background on a UIView

Comment: colorWithPatternImage will just repeat that image over the size of the view, so it will essentially just be the same size as the full image in memory, it just reduces the size of your app bundle to have a smaller image, which is always good